# Binary info to Decimal representation using circuitry

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, counter, hex

I'm tryign to make a counter (and by extension all the other things) using a series of flip-flop circuits, and a seven segment display.

As I have it the digit increments through 0xF, which isn't what I want.

I imagine that I need to capture when 1010 happens, and at that point, I need to throw this digit back to 0, and also step up a 10s digit display using the same circuit.

What logic will reset everything to 0 when the And triggers?

[image: Idea using FlipFlop circuitry]

Comment: What software is this, what are the unlabeled yellow boxes, and what's the block in the top left?

Comment: The software is a flash web site at http://www.neuroproductions.be/logic-lab/
The unlabeled yellow boxes are just junctions where the signal splits.
The top left box is a switch that acts as an initial power source.

Comment: Anthony, what you are trying to make is often referred to as a "decimal counter" or a "divide by 10 circuit". Look up a 74HCT90, 74LS90, or 74HCT390 IC for some ideas on how this is done with divide-by-2 building blocks (i.e. flip-flops).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into the [JK flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#JK_flip-flop).

[image]

It gives you a clock input so that everything changes simultaneously, but also a means to reset the outputs to zero.